# Leaflet.label Plugin Not Working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, labeling, mapbox, plugins

I am trying to use the leaflet.label plugin and have had no success getting it to recognize .bindLabel. I am a very basic user, new to Java and Leaflet. I'm trying .bindLabel with a simple, single marker as well as a series of markers loaded from a geoJSON file. Neither works, but it does run through the code and bring up the rest of the map and markers.

I feel like I am probably referencing the script wrong... I downloaded/installed it using NPM to the following folder: C:\FFS\Dashboard\node_modules\leaflet.label\

My index.html, map.html and map.js is located in C:\FFS\Dashboard\

Here's my map.html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flood Forecast Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/html5up/main.css" />-->

    <!-- MapBox -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- Leaflet 1.0.3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ADD-ONS -->

    <!-- Leaflet Label -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet.label/dist/leaflet.label.css" />
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/dist/leaflet.label-src.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/dist/leaflet.label.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/Label.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/BaseMarkerMethods.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/Marker.Label.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/CircleMarker.Label.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/Path.Label.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/Map.Label.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/FeatureGroup.Label.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leaflet.label/src/FeatureGroup.Label.js"></script>

    <!-- Fullscreen button -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- GeoJSON Files  -->

    <script src="data/json/HCFCD_Gages.JSON" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- CSS --> 
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Embedding in Image: <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map">-->
<div id="map">

</div>

<script src='map.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my map.js text:

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([29.758994, -95.3635502], 10);

    map.zoomControl.remove();

    // Basemaps

    var baseGoogleSat = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3'],
        attribution: '© Google'
    });

    var baseGoogleStreets = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    }).addTo(map);

    <!-- NEXRAD Reflectivity from Iowa State -->
    var NEXRAD_N0Q = L.tileLayer.wms("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0q.cgi", {
      layers: 'nexrad-n0q-900913',
      format: 'image/png',
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.5,
      attribution: "NEXRAD N0Q"
    }).addTo(map);

    var basemaps = {
        "2017 Google Aerial Imagery":baseGoogleSat,
        "Google Maps":baseGoogleStreets
    };

    // Layers

    //Points//

    L.circleMarker([29.758994, -95.3635502], { color: "#f00", radius: 12 }).bindLabel( "Hello World", { direction: 'left' }).addTo(map);

    var styleHCFCD_Gages = {
        radius: 4,
        fillColor: "#0ba956",
        color: "#4de595",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 1
    };

    var layerHCFCD_Gages = L.geoJSON(jsonHCFCD_Gages, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, styleHCFCD_Gages);
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
              layer.bindPopup('<h1>Gage ID:'+feature.properties.GageID+'</h1><p>Site: '+feature.properties.Location+'</p>');
              layer.bindLabel( "Hello World", { direction: 'left' });
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    var overlays = {
      "HCFCD Gages":layerHCFCD_Gages,
      "NEXRAD N0Q":NEXRAD_N0Q
    };

    //L.control.measure({position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
    L.control.fullscreen().addTo(map);
    L.control.scale().addTo(map);
    L.control.layers(basemaps, overlays, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Leaflet is normally already included in Mapbox.js (non GL). Leaflet.label plugin is deprecated with Leaflet version 1.0+, because it is already included.

Comment: How would I reference / use it then? According to https://www.mapbox.com/blog/extend-your-maps-mapboxjs-plugins/ I would add a script/link reference in the html but that didn't work (using their example of //api.tiles.../leaflet-label.js and .css). They then refer to the leaflet label github site. Aren't the files on github the same as what I downloaded through NPM? Apologies for the probably obvious question but I am new to all of this (my background is GIS with minimal programming).

Comment: Answer - Yes leaflet.label plugin is deprecated but it is now called .bindTooltip, not .bindLabel. Hence why my searching ended up a dead end. http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltipevent

Answer (score 3):

Leaflet.label plugin is deprecated (no longer active) but, importantly, it is now called **.bindTooltip, not .bindLabel**. Hence why my searching ended up a dead end.

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltipevent

Comment: This answer helped a lot. I was searching days and days why binLabel did not work. Thank you for this tip.